# Is it possible to access a specific language without specifying the language in the query string

Tags: sxa, multilingual

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7. I have created a Chinese language and a version for the language. I have added Chinese content for a page and in the site grouping of site specified the language as CN. But when I browse the page I am not able to see Chinese content. If I specify the language in the query string I am able to see the Chinese content.

In the preview mode of the page I am able to see CN content.

[image]

Is it possible to browse the CN content without specifying the language in the query string?If yes please explain how can i achieve that.

[image]

**Update**

Created a Patch File under Appconfig/Include named as sitedefinition.config and added the language and other paths as shown in the below screenshot but still I'm getting a blank page as above screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter got you on the right path by defining a default language for the site, but as you are using SXA you shouldn't (or can't) do that with a config patch. (you can remove that again)

To set a default language in SXA you just need to set it in the site definition fields for that site: https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/the-sxa-site-definition-fields.html

> You can change the site definition fields in
> `/sitecore/content/<tenant>/<site>/Settings/Site Grouping/<site>`. You
> can also access these fields from the SXA Site Manager. The SXA site
> definition items are equivalent to Sitecore  nodes that you
> define within your config file if you build the site without SXA.

Set the field `Language` to the desired default language (and publish).

Of course, if you have multiple languages you should use a language switch...

Also:

- make sure everything is published (including the language setting item and all paths from the root to your item. Might be best to do a full site publish)
- if everything still fails: I noticed that you are testing a page on a first sublevel underneath your home. Does that home item also has a Chinese version? If not, create that as well.. (to make sure there is a Chinese path al the way to your page)

Comment: I am testing this under master DB and i have changed the language in sitegrouping also @Gatogordo

Comment: And do you parent items have a Chinese version?

Comment: Yes parent item has chinese versions @Gatogordo

Comment: Does it work on the homepage? Do you have a language cookie set? (try clearing you cookies if needed and maybe an other/incognito browser so you don't share a browser with your editing environment)

Comment: No it is not working on the Home Page too and cleared the cookies also maintaing different browsers @Gatogordo

Comment: I must have been blind, haven't realized it is SXA site :-) Sorry. Will delete my answer as it's irrelevant